# GDB not able to recognise executable which is unstripped

Tags: gdb, executable, elf

I am using GDB executable in my linux machine to debug my executable(rild).

## My Executable details are as below :-

```
rild: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[md5/uuid]=d100d90599eb3764018356c9ef3e1840, not stripped
```

however when I am running the command

```
./arm-linux-androideabi-gdb ~/android_gdb/system_bin/rild
```

## I am getting follwing error:-

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html>...
"/home/user/android_gdb/system_bin/rild": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I can see  that GDB is also 64 bit version and the executable ELF is also  unstripped, 64 bit. but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

> `rild: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV),`

This is an `aarch64` 64-bit ARM binary.

> `This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-android"`

This GDB is a 64-bit `x86_64` binary, configured to debug 32-bit ARM binaries.

The fact that GDB itself is a 64-bit binary is irrelevant. What matters is what *target* it is configured to debug. You need a different GDB, configured with `--target=aarch64-linux-android`.